# RabbitMQ Memory leak when using auto-delete queue with connection/topology autorecovery

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I was having problem with memory leak in assembly `RabbitMQ.Client` - .NET client for RabbitMQ after enabling automatic recovery of connections and topology.
There were retained objects: RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection (more specifically there were dictionaries `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, RecordedConsumer>` and `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, RecordedQueue>`).

I've found useful info in [Java client documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#cache-pitfalls) for RabbitMQ client:

> However, the client cannot track these topology changes beyond a
>   single connection. Applications that rely on auto-delete queues or
>   exchanges, as well as queue TTL (note: not message TTL!), and use
>   automatic connection recovery, should explicitly delete entities know
>   to be unused or deleted, to purge client-side topology cache.

So I've decided to delete it from client's cache right after calling to `QueueDeclareOk QueueDeclare(string queue, bool durable, bool exclusive, bool autoDelete, IDictionary<string, object> arguments);`
I do it like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a queue from client's autorecovery cache when it's needed.
    /// </summary>
    private void DeleteFromRecordedQueues(string queue, IDictionary<string, object> queueArgs)
    {
        if (!RabbitMqUtils.IsTemporaryQueue(queueArgs))
            return;

        var autoRecoveringConnection = connection as AutorecoveringConnection;
        if (autoRecoveringConnection == null)
            return;

        autoRecoveringConnection.DeleteRecordedQueue(queue);
    }
```

Approximately the same I do for consumer, using this method `public RecordedConsumer DeleteRecordedConsumer(string consumerTag)`

This approach is OK for short-living queues,
But what if my queue time-to-live is set to a long period (for example 30 minutes), and I want it to auto-recover in case of network problems?

My colleague suggested that I use job, checking `RecordedQueues` against all queues existing on the server, and run my `DeleteFromRecordedQueues` in case it does not exist anymore. But I do not like this solution as I believe this problem must be solved using standard client library fuctionality.

Is it possible to escape memory leak and not lose autorecovery functionality for the auto-delete queue?

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639658/python-komburabbitmq-deadlock-queues-are-either-blocked-or-blocking

Comment: @cantSleepNow, you've mentioned answer about memory leak in a management module.
The reason for leak in my case is clear, and I'm asking about the best soltuion for it.
Moreover, my server verison is 3.6.0, while the [described problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639658/python-komburabbitmq-deadlock-queues-are-either-blocked-or-blocking) occurred in 3.6.2.